# Dial SIP number using native/system dialler

Tags: android, sip

I have an app which creates a SIP profile using `SipProfile.Builder` and I'm able to place a SIP call using that profile by calling `makeAudioCall()`.

I was wondering if it's possible to get the native dialler to use my SIP profile to place a call using an Intent? I tried invoking the native dialler via an intent:

```
Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);       
Uri call = Uri.parse("sip:123455@sip.domain.com");  

dial.setData(call);
dial.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                       
startActivity(dial);
```

but it does not place the call from the SIP profile my app created.

What I want is to avoid re-inventing the wheel in creating my own custom dialler UI and reuse the native dialler for this.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you manage to resolve the problem...

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Ended up building my own dialer UI